# How to use a permutation of operators in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators

I saw this puzzle in the newspaper where you are given 5 numbers (8,5,2,6,3). The question was in which order you have to place the operators (+,-,*,/) between the numbers to get the largest outcome. 
You can't change the order of the numbers and you have to use each operator once.

This is my second week ever of learning to code. I created the solution below. It is working but the actual calculation doesn't look clean. Can you help me in finding a cleaner way?

Also if you have any recommendations to optimize the rest of the code, let me know. Thanks alot for any help!

(PS: I do know that the mathematical order of the operators is not respected in this solution. It just reads from left to right. But first I am trying to clean the easy version. Afterwards I'll try to make it more complicated.)

```
from itertools import permutations
import operator

ops = {'+' : operator.add, '-' : operator.sub, '*' : operator.mul, '/' : operator.truediv} #Dict necessary to make the formula work.
perm = permutations(["+","-","*","/"]) #Store all possible combinations of the four operators in a tuple.

getallen=[]

def input_split(getallen): #Split the string inputted by the user into separate integers.
    lijst_2=[]
    lijst = getallen.split(",")
    for i in lijst:
        lijst_2.append(int(i))
    return lijst_2

def determine_max (getallen, perm): #Test which order of operators returns the highest number.
    maximum=0
    for i in perm: 
        temp_max = ops[f"{i[3]}"](ops[f"{i[2]}"](ops[f"{i[1]}"](ops[f"{i[0]}"](getallen[0], getallen[1]), getallen[2]), getallen[3]), getallen[4])
        if temp_max > maximum:
            maximum = temp_max
        else:
            pass

    return maximum

getallen = input("Give 5 comma separated numbers\n")
getallen = input_split(getallen)
max_output = determine_max (getallen, perm)
print(max_output)
```

Comment: If your code is complete and works, it should be on [codereview.se]. This site is primarily for fixing broken code.

Comment: Since you have complete control over the input, I would just construct strings like `'8+5*2-6/3'` and use `eval` to evaluate them. `max(..., key=eval)` would come in handy, as would `itertools.chain` and `itertools.zip_longest`.

Comment: (By "complete control", I was assuming 8, 5, 2, 6, and 3 were fixed. Your `input_split` looks complete enough to ensure that your input is safe, though.)

Answer (score 0):

> permutations(iterable, r=None)
>
> Return successive r-length permutations of elements in the iterable.

Here is my code for get_maximum

```py
from itertools import permutations

def get_maximum(number):

    lst = list(map(list, permutations(operator, 4)))
    result = []
    for item in lst:
        item_list = [str(number[0])]
        for i in range(4):
            item_list.append(item[i])
            item_list.append(str(number[i+1]))
        expression = ''.join(item_list)
        result.append((expression, eval(expression)))

    solution = sorted(result, key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)

    return solution[0]

number = (8, 5, 2, 6, 3)
operator = ['+','-', '*', '/']
print(get_maximum(number))    # ('8*5-2/6+3', 42.666666666666664)
```